# Why is RhinoMocks throwing an InvalidOperationException at my test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd, rhino-mocks

This is a test I am currently working on:
(Edited according to Lees answer)

```
[Test]
public void AddLockClassWithNullNameShouldCallInsertOnSessionWithEmptyString()
{
    LockClass lockClass = new LockClass { Id = ValidId, Name = null };

    using ( mockRepository.Record() ) {
        sessionFactory.CreateSession();
        LastCall.Return( session );

        session.InsertWithId( lockClass );
        LastCall.Return( lockClass );

        session.Commit();
        session.Dispose();
    }

    using ( mockRepository.Playback() ) {
        controller = new LockClassPanelController( sessionFactory );
        controller.AddLockClass( lockClass.Id, string.Empty );
    }

    mockRepository.VerifyAll();
}
```

Running the test results in:

```
Test 'Test.Unit.Controllers.LockClassPanelControllerTests.AddLockWithNullNameClassShouldCallInsertOnSessionWithEmptyString' failed:
 System.InvalidOperationException : The operation is invalid because of the current object state. (translated from german, dunno if thats the original english wording)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
 at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.MethodsEquals(MethodInfo method, ProxyMethodExpectationTriplet triplet)
 at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.GetAllExpectationsForProxyAndMethod(Object proxy, MethodInfo method)
 at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.CalcExpectedAndActual.Calculate(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
 at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.CalcExpectedAndActual..ctor(UnorderedMethodRecorder parent, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
 at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.UnexpectedMethodCall(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
 at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.DoGetRecordedExpectation(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
 at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.MethodRecorderBase.GetRecordedExpectation(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
 at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.ReplayMockState.DoMethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
 at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.ReplayMockState.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
 at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
 at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RhinoInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
 at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
 at ISessionProxy2762dfaac4274133bc97e10d4e5c35d0.InsertWithId[TEntity](TEntity entity)
 Controllers\LockClassPanelController.cs(20,0): at Artea.Service.Controllers.LockClassPanelController.AddLockClass(Int32 id, String name)
 Unit\Controllers\LockClassPanelControllerTests.cs(80,0): at Test.Unit.Controllers.LockClassPanelControllerTests.AddLockWithNullNameClassShouldCallInsertOnSessionWithEmptyString()
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I just figured out that it works fine if the first line of the method is changed:

```
LockClass lockClass = new LockClass { Id = ValidId, Name = string.Empty };
```

(`string.Empty` instead of `null`)
But the test is supposed to check what happens if the `Name` property is null, so having `Name` being anything else but `null` would not be very helpful.

**Edit:**
The code is actually not testing what i I wanted to test. The first line of the method should be

```
LockClass lockClass = new LockClass { Id = ValidId, Name = string.Empty };
```

Thats my expected object. `LockClass` is a DTO with only the two properties initialized in above line and the obligatory `Equals` stuff.
The act line should be

```
controller.AddLockClass( lockClass.Id, null );
```

[SetUp] creates all the mocked objects. What I am trying to test is that if the user creates a LockClass object though GUI gestures (the GUI calls `AddLockClass` on the controller) where the name is null the controller creates an object with an empty name. There are other ways to do that, but right now it has to be this way. The changed code does work (e.g. Rhino does not throw up). I am still keeping the question because it is curious why Rhino does not like the original code.

To make it complete:

```
private const int ValidId = 4711;
private const int InvalidId = 0;
private MockRepository mockRepository;
private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
private ISession session;
private LockClassPanelController controller;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    mockRepository = new MockRepository();
    sessionFactory = mockRepository.StrictMock<ISessionFactory>();
    session = mockRepository.StrictMock<ISession>();
}
```

**Edit:**

```
public void AddLockClass( int id, string name )
{
    if ( id != 0 ) {
        using ( var session = sessionFactory.CreateSession() ) {
            session.InsertWithId( new LockClass { Id = id, Name = name } );
            session.Commit();
        }
        LoadLockClasses();
        view.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: controller.AddLockClass( lockClass.Id, string.Empty );

Comment: What's the signature of controller.AddLockClass()?  What is sessionFactory?  What is session?  Where are they created?  Are they mocks too?

Comment: Everything but the LockClassPanelController is mocked (it's a *unit* test after all).  

`AddLockClass(int id, string name)`

Comment: sessionFactory is a ISessionFactory which creates sessions (ISession, DB access sessions, hand rolled DAL). But it does not matter, because they are mocked anyway.

Comment: Does it really still throw the same exception? Could you paste the code of your AddLockClass method?

Comment: Yes, it still throws the same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rhino Mocks gives you correct exception. In your AddLockClass you have the following line:

```
session.InsertWithId( new LockClass { Id = id, Name = ( name ?? string.Empty ) } );
```

which clearly indicates that if you call this method with null name parameter, it will still use empty string when creating the LockClass instance. So as you noticed in the first edit of your question, the LockClass that you should expect in your test is:

```
LockClass lockClass = new LockClass { Id = ValidId, Name = string.Empty };
```

and *not* the version with null. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: `?? string.Empty` is not supposed to be there (I will edit it). Please read my various edits. The whole semantics of the test were wrong (not what I wanted to test). But still it is curious why rhino throws that exception. It should not care about the Name property being null.

Comment: It is very simple. You set the expectation session.InsertWithId( lockClass ); LastCall.Return( lockClass ); Rhino expects exactly this call and will compare the arguments (lock class) using the Equals method. That's why it does matter if its null or empty string. I am not sure how you would like to test it without comparing the arguments.

Comment: Grzenio is correct.  You set up an expectation that a specific LockClass will be returned but inside your method, you create a new instance of a LockClass.  Thus, the test fails.  I'm not sure why you got the exception though.  I tried to create a complete test using Rhino.Mocks 3.5 and I get a failing test, not an exception: http://pastebin.com/1Kb9ZxTK

Comment: LockClass implements Equals() so that two instances with the same id and the same name are considered equal.

You implemented the test with MsTest. Maybe it is a problem with NUnit. I will try to create an isolated setup to reproduce the exception.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to enclose the 'act' part of the test inside a playback scope:

```
using(mockRepository.Playback())
{
    controller = new LockClassPanelController( sessionFactory ); 
    controller.AddLockClass( lockClass.Id, string.Empty );
}

mockRepository.VerifyAll();
```

Comment: It still throws the same exception.